# Casting pointers to ints

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I have a number of xmlChar * in my source file and I need them to be in integer form.

How does one cast these correctly?

When I tried this `world->representation = malloc(sizeof(int *) * mapHeight);` it says

```
error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘long unsigned int’ and ‘xmlChar *’)
```

and when I tried this

```
world->representation = malloc(sizeof(int *) * (int) mapHeight);
```

I got this error

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_main", referenced from:
>         start in crt1.10.6.o
>     "_commandfetcher", referenced from:
>         _commandFetcher in ccPv5Pvd.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

How can I cast a xmlChar pointer to an int? e.g the xmlChar has the value of 30, I need this in int form.

Comment: `mapHeight` points to a string containing "30" - that is *not* the same as "having the value 30". You'll need to use atoi/strtol to convert, it is not a *cast*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simply cast a `char` to an `int`. (Or rather, you can, but it doesn't do what you think it does.)

Use [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/) to convert a string to an integer:

```
char* number = "30";
int value = strtol(number, NULL, 0);
```

Comment: That needs to be `long int`, not `int`.  What's the difference between `strtol()` and `atol()`?

Comment: `strtol` allows you to specify which base you're using, can parse hex, and will optionally give you a pointer to the end of the parsed string. See the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to cast the pointer - you want to dereference it.

But in this case you probably want to convert the string into an integer?